# Euler's totient function relative function

Tags: nt.number-theory

For the $\sigma$ function, the ratio $\sigma(m)/m$ is known as the *abundancy index*. Is there any special name for $\phi(m)/m$ with $\phi$ the Euler's totient function ?

Comment: I don't think it has a name, but its reciprocal is closely related to the abundancy index (it has the same density), see http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2007-135-09/S0002-9939-07-08771-0/S0002-9939-07-08771-0.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I called it $\pi^{-1}(m)$ in a number theory article I posted on the ArXiv.  I did not scour the literature, but I conjecture that Erdos never came up with a name for it (he didn't in the papers I saw that talked about the quantity), and I would also like to know if anyone else did.

Gerhard "No Need For A Link" Paseman, 2015.09.02

Comment: I also did it in the Westzynthius question that I occasionally promote.  I wrote a manifesto in which I  suggested the quantity deserved more attention, and then decided I had gone too far, and kept myself from posting it online.  Gerhard "Doesn't Mean I Was Wrong" Paseman, 2015.09.02

Comment: Why did you denote it like this? Is there some relation to the prime counting function I am missing?

Comment: Different context.  I used sigma ^ -1 for the sum of reciprocals of distinct prime divisors, and pi ^ -1 for product of (1 - reciprocal).  I was dealing with counting consecutive nontotatives (non coprimes), not primes.  Gerhard "Seemed Natural At The Time" Paseman, 2015.09.02

Comment: Also, while there may be a relation between $\pi(x)$ and $\pi^{-1}(m)$, I never planned to use the two in the same article.  Gerhard "Like Edward Teller And Anti-Teller" Paseman, 2015.09.02

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I can follow the reasoning.